# PostgreSQL - long query just halts

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, database-tuning

I have a materialized view based on a very complex (and not very efficient) query. This materialized view is used for BI/visualization. It often takes ~4 minutes to complete the refresh, which is good enough for my needs. Running `ANALYZE` shows total cost of 2,116,446 with 137,682 rows and 1,976 width.

However, sometimes `refresh materialize view XXX` just never completes. Looking at the top processes (`top` in ubuntu), the process will use 100% CPU and 8.1% (of the server's 28GB memory) for a while... then all of a sudden it just disappears from the `top` list. It usually happens after ~4-5 minutes (although `statement_timeout` config is disabled). The postgres client just keeps waiting forever, and the view never refreshes.

Running the query behind the view directly (i.e. `SELECT ...`) will fail as well (same issue).

I'm using version 9.5. I've tried to increase `effective_cache_size`, `shared_buffers`, and `work_mem` in postgres config, but still the same result.

Sometimes, after several attempts, the refresh command will complete successfully. But it's unpredictable and currently just wouldn't work even after multiple attempts / db restarts.

Any suggestions to what might be the problem?

Comment: If it is disappearing from `top`, then congratulations!  You managed to make the server crash.  You should try to reduce your problem to a simple test case and then [report it to the developers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/bug-reporting.html).

Comment: @Kevin I disagree. If it crashes, the client will notice. My money is on a lock. When a backend is locked, it stops consuming CPU.

Comment: Could be just the OOM killer. First: check the postgres logfile.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe and @joop! I looked at postgres logfile in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log` but it doesn't have anything useful (is that the log file you meant?)
I'd be surprised if it's the OOM killer because it only uses 8.1% of the available 28GB memory.
Any thoughts about how to go about the lock? Other directions?

Comment: Yes. Check the `pg_locks` view when the problem occurs and see if there are any locks with `granted = false`.

Comment: No locks with `granted = false`. Before I ran the refresh, there were 2 locks (granted). While it ran, 32-38 locks. And then when the problem occurred just immediately dropped to 2 again. Seems like something just stops the query / causes it to suddenly halt... 
I tried refresh `CONCURRENTLY` but same result. Just stops after 4 minutes and a few seconds.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I was assuming that "disappears from `top`" means *disappears* from `top`, not just "drops to a much lower point in the list."

Comment: @Kevin We're both guessing :^) `top` only shows the top processes. @aei: What's your operating system and PostgreSQL version? Since you say the problem occurs with the `SELECT` alone, let's focus on that. Can you add the query and the table definitions to the question? Ideally with `EXPLAIN` output so we know what the DB does. When the query "just hangs" and doesn't consume CPU, can you follow https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend to get a stack trace of the backend?